# Mongodb database not getting rendered into table created with react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am working on a MERN project that requires to fetch assets from database. The data is appearing in console but the same is not getting rendered into the table.There is no error on warning.[image of the output with console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtuq4.jpg)

Below are my react component and server code. I have attached database screenshot.[Database image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oneK.jpg)

```
import {React,useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import NavBar from '../Shared/Navbar';
import axios from 'axios'


function AssetList() {
                              
const [asset,setAsset] = useState([])

   const getAssets = ()=>  {
          
                 axios.get('http://localhost:6001/assets/get-assets')
                  .then((res)=>{
                      setAsset([res.data])
                      console.log(res.data)
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    // setLoading(false);
                })
              
       }
      //  console.log(asset)

useEffect(()=>{
  // setAsset (getAssets())
  getAssets();
},[])


  return (
    <>
     <NavBar/>
    
  <table className="table-bordered">
   <thead>
   <tr>
       <td>Full Name</td>
       <td>Model</td>
       <td>Serial</td>
         </tr>
        </thead>

             <tbody>
          {
         asset.map((item,k)=>{
              return(
                <tr key={k}>
                   <td>{item.fullName}</td>
                  <td>{item.model}</td>
                  <td>{item.serial}</td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
          }
             </tbody>
       </table>

    
    </>
  )
}

export default AssetList
```

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose, { Error } from "mongoose";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from 'cors';
import assetrouter from "./router/assetDetail.router";

const app = express()
const port = 6001

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var corsOptions = {
    // origin: 'http://localhost:5000',---
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // For legacy browser support
    methods: "GET, PUT, PATCH,  POST, DELETE"
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/vaibhav")
 .then(()=>{
    console.log("Database Connected Successfuly!!!!")})
 .catch((err)=>{ 
    console.log("Error:",err)})

    app.use('/assets',assetrouter)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change
`setAsset([res.data])`
to be  `setAsset([...res.data])` or `setAsset(res.data)`

update :

Here's what you can do to fix the problem:

Update the getAssets function to properly format the response data:

```
const getAssets = () => {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:6001/assets/get-assets')
    .then((res) => {
      const data = res.data; // assuming the response data is an array of objects
      setAsset(data); // set the state to the formatted data
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

In the asset.map function, you need to access the object properties by their names instead of trying to access them directly from the array:

```
    {
  asset.map((item, k) => {
    return (
      <tr key={k}>
        <td>{item.fullName}</td>
        <td>{item.model}</td>
        <td>{item.serial}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

Also, make sure that you have imported the required modules such as React and useState correctly.

Comment: setAsset([...res.data]) is showing "TypeError: Spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function "  and   setAsset(res.data) is showing "asset.map is not a function"

Comment: so please try to console the `res` to make sure if `res` includes `data ` property as an array or if the `res` is mainly the array that you want and please if you can attach screenshot from you console

Comment: i have already attached a screenshot of the console in my post. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `setAsset([res.data])` to `setAsset(res.data)`. This assumes that the API response is an array of objects representing individual assets.

Comment: setAsset(res.data) is showing "asset.map is not a function"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).